# How to save data from a webpage into Django database without using a form?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to save data from my webpage into my Django database. The data does not come from a form - I have built a web-based game with a timer and I would like to store the end value of the timer in my database for each game once the user presses the 'finish' button. The data doesn't come from a form as the timer increments automatically every second and stops when the finish button is pressed - how would i go about saving this to my django database?

this is what the django model looks like:

```
class Games(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    solveTime = models.IntegerField()
    hintsCount = models.IntegerField()
    difficultyChoices = [
        ('E', 'easy'),
        ('M', 'medium'),
        ('H', 'hard')
    ]
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=difficultyChoices, default='M')
```

so for example i would like to be able to send a POST request to the server with `{timer: 300, hints:2}` which can then be saved with the above model

thanks :)

Comment: You can still use a form: you do *not* have to *render* the form in HTML: a form can also be used to validate, clean and save data without having anything to do with the front end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how would i do that? - thanks btw

Comment: use ajax to POST data to the backend  ( timer and hints ) .... here's a simple implementation of Django Ajax form POSTing...   [ https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html  ]